# setImageResource with JSON data

Tags: android, json

How can I set images which I get as JSON to imageview? Below is my code..

```
 try {
               JSONObject responseObject = json.getJSONObject("responseData");
               JSONArray resultArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("results");
               private ArrayList<Object> listImages;
               listImages = getImageList(resultArray);
               } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now, I want to set images to imageview as below...

```
 private int[] GalImages = new int[] { R.drawable.h, R.drawable.i};
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
            imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
            imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);

            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;
        }
```

Here I've set by default images from drawable folder, but I've to set images which I get as json, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

> Here I've set by default images from drawable folder, but I've to set
>   images which I get as json, how can I do this?

for showing image from web url which you are getting in JSON returned from server you will need to first download images in available cache or storage. after downloading image get bitmap and pass it to `ImageView.setImageBitmap`

```
   private Bitmap download_Image(String url) {

        Bitmap bmp =null;
        try{
            URL ulrn = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)ulrn.openConnection();
            InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            if (null != bmp)
                return bmp;

            }catch(Exception e){}
        return bmp;
    }
```

call `download_Image` method using `AsyncTask` or `Handler` to avoid `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

if you are using  ListView or GridView Views then use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: can't I do this without downloading?

Comment: @thumbernirmal : yes it's not possible to set src to ImageView from url